# ¿Cómo puedo solucionar Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, formularios

Estoy intentando hacer que un email se compruebe en el mismo momento a través de ajax pero a la hora de hacer la parte de ajax me dan los siguientes errores en la consola y no se ejecuta el "success":

ACTUALIZACIÓN DE CÓDIGO JAVASCRIPT

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier load.php:103

Code HTML:

```
                <div class="form_email">
                <label for="email">
                    ¿Cuál es su e-mail? <span class="info_email">Solo lo usaremos para enviarte actualizaciones sobre tu postulación. </span>
                </label>
                <input type="text" id="form_emailz" name="email" pattern="[^@\s]+@[^@\s]+\.[^@\s]+" title="Introduzca un email correcto." maxlength="30" required />
               
            </div>
            <div class="form_movil">
                <label for="numero">
                    ¿Cuál es su número de teléfono? <span class="info_numero">Lo necesitaremos para ponernos en contacto contigo. </span>
                </label>
                <input type="number" id="form_movilz" name="movil" pattern="[0-9]{9}" maxlength="12" title="Introduzca un número de teléfono correcto, sin el +34" required />
            </div>
 <button class="form_send" id="form_sende" type="submit" name="submit">Enviar Formulario</button>
```

Code Js:

```
 <script>
    $(function (){

       
           $("#form_sende").on('click',function(e){
        
        e.preventDefault();
        var email = $("#form_emailz").val();
        var numero = $("#form_movilz").val();

        $.ajax({
            type:  "POST",
            url: "assets/php/send.php",
            data: ("email="+email+"&numero="+numero),
            success: function(respuesta){
               // alert(stmt->execute);
            }
        })
        
        })
        
})
    
    </script>
```

PHP:

```
$prueba = "si";
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {   


if($prueba == si){
    echo 'hecho';
}
else{
    echo 'error';
}
```

Comment: Esto: `if($prueba == si){` no es válido, ¿**`si`** es un string o una constante?, si es lo primero le falta estar entre comillas

Comment: Vale, ya he corregido eso, se me habia pasado, pero aún sigue dando el mismo error @BetaM

Comment: Claramente te falta cerrar el `if` del inicio. ¿o fue un error de tipeo?

Comment: Error de tipeo @JonatanLavado

Comment: El error es claro, sólo debes buscar las líneas `30` y `126` de tu código y ponerlas aquí. Dado que es un error de sintaxis es difícil saber qué es exactamente sólo con eso. Lo más probable es que sea una `}` o algún caracter de más.

Comment: @JonatanLavado el problema es que esas líneas no corresponden con mi código de javascript, he logrado resolver un error, pero el otro ahí sigue

Answer (score 0):

hay varios errores, especialmente en el archivo php ya que esta captando al submit pero este ya se ha procesado mediante una llamada con jquery

```
$("#form_sende").on('click',function(e){
```

por lo cual quedaria a si:

```
if(isset($_POST['email'],$_POST['numero'])){
   echo 'hecho';
}else{
   echo 'error';
}
```

o también con base en el code que postea seria así:

```
$prueba = "si";
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {   

if($prueba == "si"){
    echo 'hecho';
}
else{
    echo 'error';
    }
}
```

aunque es una forma incorrecta ya que el if siempre será verdadero aun sin verificar  los datos que se le pasan por vía ajax

por otro lado el js esta mal

```
<script>   
       
    $("#form_sende").on('click',function(){

        var email = $("#form_emailz").val();
        var numero = $("#form_movilz").val();

        $.ajax({
            type:  "POST",
            url: "assets/php/send.php",
            data: {"email="email + "numero="numero},
            success: function(respuesta){
               console.log(respuesta);
            }
        })
        
        })
    
    </script>
```

Comment: He modificado mi código pero sigue apareciendo el mismo error en la consola:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier